# Why won't this template function compile C++

Tags: c++, function, templates

I saw this code in the internet:

```
template <class T, class S>
    T f(T& a, T& b, S c) {
    T t1, t2, t3;
    if (a==b) return t1;
    if (c>0) return t2;
    return t3;
}
```

Followed by these calls:

```
f('c', 5, 5); // why this doesn't compile?

f(3, 4, 6.0);  // why does this compile?
```

The first one doesn't compile, while the second does.. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a reference when passing in a literal?

Comment: The template specification anticipates that parameters `a` and `b` should be the same type.  They are not in the first one, but they are in the second one.

Comment: [Second sample doesn't compile either](http://ideone.com/aBWO1Y)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ someone's using MSVC, one feels

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So copy constructor and operator `==` are needed for `S` and copy constructor and operator `>` are needed for `T` ?

Comment: @M.M I know it's little relevant to OP's question, but why does MSVC allow the second invocation? `T` should be `const`.

Comment: @DeanSeo historical reasons I guess...  they started doing it before the first C++ standard came out, and then they didn't want to break existing code

Comment: @M.M Woah, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ (as opposed to C) `'c'` is a `char`.

Your code does not compile because template argument deduction for parameter `T` fails - it is ambiguous. In `f('c', 5, 5)` call the first function argument says it should be `char`, the second says it should be `int`. How did you expect the compiler to resolve this ambiguity?

If you want `T == int` you can specify the first template argument explicitly

```
f<int>('c', 5, 5);
```

or you can use an explicit cast

```
f((int) 'c', 5, 5);
```

Of course, as it has already been noted, even if you get through the template argument deduction issues, you still won't be able to initialize non-constant lvalue references with rvalues. Both of your calls are invalid too, for this latter reason.

Comment: but isn't `'c'` an `int`?

Comment: @meer khan: No, in C++ `'c'` is a `char`. In C it is an `int`, but C++ is not C.

Comment: How does rvalue bind to (non const) `T&` in call to `f(3, 4, 6.0);`?

Comment: @Zereges: Probably through a compiler extension of some kind. E.g. internally it might behave the same way it would if the parameters were declared as `const T&`. But in standard C++ it doesn't bind. In standard C++ the second call is invalid as well for that specific reason.